# getting predicted values from an nls() model for Fabens von Bertalanffy growth curve

Tags: r, curve-fitting, predict, nls

I have a growth dataset based off of recaptures. There are columns with the capture length, the recapture length, and the time (in yrs) based off the recapture minus the capture.

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   60 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ sizecapture  : num  40.3 43 38.3 41.5 37.6 ...
 $ sizerecapture: num  43 48.7 39.5 42 46.7 43.5 43.5 47.2 45.7 59.9 ...
 $ timeinterval : num  0.945 1.036 0.997 0.997 2.471 ...
```

I am following Ogle 2013 vignette (http://derekogle.com/fishR/examples/oldFishRVignettes/VonBertalanffyExtra.pdf) in R, for the Fabens method of trying to derive size at age. For this method I don't need an initial age (as I don't know age at all). I am not interested in extrapolating, but for only estimating the age of individuals that I have sizes for.

I can easily follow the instructions for calculating the two parameters needed to inform the nls model: the k and the Linf. My aim is to create a age at length curve with the growth data, but when I get errors when I try to fitPlot. I get the error "Error in mdl$model[[gpos[2]]] : subscript out of bounds". I have also tried curve() and get the error "Error in FVB1(x) : could not find function "FVB1".

I also can't figure out how to extract the confidence intervals that fit with the predicted data.

I have searched and have found some similar cases but nothing that has worked. I'll continue to research, but am I missing something very basic? Below is a subsample of the data. I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you

```
install.packages("FSA")
install.packages("FSAdata")
install.packages("nlstools")
install.packages(car)

library(FSA)
library(FSAdata)
library(nlstools)
library(car)


sizecapture <- c(40.30,43.00,38.30,41.50,37.60,41.63,41.80,38.40,40.00,41.20,37.70,41.70,43.70,41.80,42.70,44.60,45.50,44.50,45.60,44.80,47.00,49.20,44.50,45.20,46.40,46.90,49.40,61.00,36.50,42.10,43.90,43.90,46.40,45.50,47.20,64.30,43.00,59.90,39.60,36.80)

sizerecapture < c(43.0,48.7,39.5,42.0,46.7,43.5,43.5,47.2,45.7,59.9,48.1,46.5,45.7,49.1,48.7,47.1,46.9,48.3,47.2,53.7,52.0,51.2,56.2,56.3,57.5,57.7,55.4,74.5,45.6,44.9,46.7,51.0,49.4,58.0,56.8,71.6,43.8,44.6,43.7,41.9)

timeinterval <-c(0.9452055,1.0356164,0.9972603,0.9972603,2.4712329,0.9534247,1.1945205,2.0027397,1.3178082,4.5342466,2.1863014,0.9178082,1.1315068,2.3698630,2.0575342,1.3835616,1.1726027,1.1972603,3.1698630,1.9589041,1.0712329,0.9150685,2.5671233,2.7780822,3.2000000,2.2246575,1.9150685,4.1753425,0.9287671,1.0328767,1.3945205,2.6739726,0.9205479,3.1479452,1.9506849,1.7178082,1.0520548,3.0767123,1.3726027,1.2520548)

data <- data.frame(sizecapture, sizerecapture, timeinterval)

### using Ogle 2013 to calculate Linf and k 

# k and Linf
with(data,mean((log(sizerecapture)-log(sizecapture))/timeinterval)) 
#0.0676`
max(data$sizerecapture) # largest size is 74.5
Fabens.sv <- list(Linf=74.5, K=0.0676)

# declare the model
fvb <- vbFuns("Fabens")

# fit and summarize
FVB1<- nls(sizerecapture~ 
fvb(sizecapture,timeinterval,Linf,K),start=Fabens.sv,data=data)
summary(FVB1,correlation=TRUE)

# confidence intervals through bootstrapping
boot <- nlsBoot(FVB1, niter=500)
confint(boot,plot=TRUE)

# plotting a fitted line plot 
ages2plot <- 0:40
LCI <- UCI <- numeric(length(ages2plot))
fitPlot(FVB1, xlim=range(ages2plot))
estes <- boot$coefboot
for (i in 1:length(ages2plot))  {
pv <-estes[,"Linf"]*(1-exp(-ests[,"K]*(ages2plot)))
LCI[i] <- quantile(pv,0.025)
UCI[i] <- quantile(pv,0.975)
}
lines(UCI~ages2plot,type="1")
lines(LCI~ages2plot,type="1")

# tried to just get a visual and errors arise
curve(FVB1)
```

Comment: This isn't reproducible since the library statements are missing and the data shown is not in the format needed by the read.csv statement.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, thanks. I hope that now works

Comment: I get as far as `fitPlot(FVB1, xlim=range(ages2plot))` and get an error ("Error in mdl$model[[gpos[2]]] : subscript out of bounds") ...

Comment: The help page for `fitPlot` says "DEPRECATED", although I'm not sure what you're supposed to do instead. There's no indication that `curve()` was ever expected to work. The vignette doesn't seem to use it ... ?

Comment: I spent quite a while looking at this, with no luck so far. The main thing I see that looks weird is that it looks like `fvb()` is meant to capture a **growth rate** (the formula is `(Linf - Lm) * (1 - exp(-K * dt))`, which is a linearly **decreasing** function of the initial size. It seems as though you are using it to fit a size at recapture, rather than a growth rate (i.e. you should put `sizerecapture - sizecapture` on the left side of the formula ... ?)

Comment: @BenBolker, thanks for looking at it. I also can't figure it out. I am contacting the person who made the vignette as well, I don't know if it'll offer more clarity